# How to detact the encoding using mb_detect_encoding correct?

Tags: php, character-encoding, detection

I want to detect encoding correct, but i found mb_detect_encoding always get error result, And I added lots of encoding_list UTF8 ISO-8859-* ....

Answer (score 14):

You are trying to do something that only **sometimes** works. Encoding detection is not a exact "science" so the best thing you can do is to avoid it.