# PHP: Is it possible to correctly SUBSTR a UTF-8 string?

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, substring

I have (in an SQLite database) the following string:

`Лампа в вытяжке на кухне меняется, начиная с вытаскивания белого штырька справа.`

The string is correctly shown by PHP using `print`. I would like to obtain just the first 50 chars of this string, i.e.

`Лампа в вытяжке на кухне меняется, начиная с вытас`.

I have tried using **both the substr and mb_substr**, and get

`Лампа в вытяжке на кухне ме�`, i.e. only 28 chars.

After reading here and elsewhere about the problems of mbstring, I realise that this is actually a 50 byte string (22 Russian chars = 44 bytes plus 5 spaces plus 1 question symbol).

Is there any nice solution to this? All my strings are UTF-8, so I could of course program a substr-function myself, by checking the first bit of every byte etc. But this should surely have been done before, right?

UPDATE: I believe `mb_substr` does not work properly because `mb_detect_encoding()` [does not work properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846201/).

Comment: You say that you've tried `mb_substr`, but have you tried to specify the encoding? Does `mb_substr($string, 0, 10, "UTF-8")` for example work?

Comment: Make sure you pass the right encoding to `mb_substr` - `mb_substr($input, 0, 50, 'UTF-8')` works for me, `mb_substr($input, 0, 50)` doesn't.

Comment: @h2ooooooo: I haven't, I missed it in the manual. And it does. Please add your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @texnic Don't worry about it, you should rather accept Abid's answer as that seems way more describing and useful for people searching for this problem in the future.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As usual, the answer appears to have been here. (Honestly, I have searched for about an hour)

An answer at [(鉑) string functions and UTF8 in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5760507/string-functions-and-utf8-in-php) reads:

> Make sure you set the proper internal encoding: mb_internal_encoding('utf-8');

With this **mb_internal_encoding('utf-8');** everything works fine. Sorry to bother you guys, thanks for help.

Comment: As mentioned in my comment on the OP, I'm sure that `mb_substr($string, 0, 50, "UTF-8")` would've also worked, but I'm glad you found your solution (and hey, it's a much better solution if you're using `mb_substr` a lot of different places!)

Answer (score 25):

See below URL:

**Extracting a substring from a UTF-8 string in PHP**

http://osc.co.cr/extracting-a-substring-from-a-utf-8-string-in-php/

**PHP substring with UTF-8**

http://greekgeekz.blogspot.in/2010/11/php-substring-with-utf-8.html

**Or try it:**

**Example #1**

```
$str1 = utf8_encode("Feliz día");

$str2 = substr($str1, 0, 9);

echo utf8_decode($str2); 

// will output Feliz d�
```

**Example #2**

```
$str3 = mb_substr($str1, 0, 9, 'UTF-8');

echo utf8_decode($str3); 

// will output Feliz dí
```

As of PHP >= 5.3 you can also declare the encoding directive and use the substr function

**Example #3**

```
declare(encoding='UTF-8');

$str4 = "Feliz día";

$str5 = substr($str4, 0, 9);echo $str5;


// will output Feliz dí
```

Comment: Though everything works, I like Example #3 most of all: it's better to use a single function. However, `declare` manual says: "The encoding declare value is ignored in PHP 5.3 unless php is compiled with --enable-zend-multibyte. Note that PHP does not expose whether --enable-zend-multibyte was used to compile PHP other than by phpinfo()." I believe, I'll stick to mb_ functions for now.

Answer (score 14):

Try [`mb_strcut()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strcut.php).
Its behavior is same to `substr()`, except it doesn't leave the last character to be broken.
If at the position you are trying to cut out, have a multibyte character with 2 or more bytes, `mb_strcut()` will not cut the character into pieces, but will ignore this character.

For instance, if your are trying to cut out 50 bytes out of the string `Лампа в вытяжке на кухне меняется, начиная с вытаскивания белого штырька справа.`, `mb_strcut()` will not cut the character `н` in half, but will eliminate it from the result.

```
$str = "Лампа в вытяжке на кухне меняется, начиная с вытаскивания белого штырька справа.";

echo mb_strcut($str, 0, 50);
// Prints: Лампа в вытяжке на кухне ме

echo substr($str, 0, 50);
// Prints: Лампа в вытяжке на кухне ме�

echo mb_substr($str, 0, 50);
// Prints: Лампа в вытяжке на кухне меняется, начиная с вытас
```

Hope it helps.