# Php text encode

Tags: php

I have this some code that will auto generate a string but some of the special characters is shown like: �

Code:

```
header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
function RandomString($length = 10){
    $chars ='0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzåäöABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZÅÄÖ!#¤%&()=?@£$€{}[]+';
    $randString = '';
    for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++){
        $randString .= $chars[rand(0, 88)];
    }
    echo $randString;
    return $randString;
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to "Encode" "Encrypt" or "Hash" the string.. there is a big difference between the three.

Comment: @OrelEraki how do you think that function is meant to encrypt or hash something? Clearly, this is a question about character encoding.

Comment: php has no notion of your string being a string with utf8 characters - `A string is series of characters, where a character is the same as a byte. This means that PHP only supports a 256-character set, and hence does not offer native Unicode support.` - see http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php and especially the details of the string type.

Comment: The encoding of your source file must also be UTF-8 to work this code. And you should use special "Unicode" function to extract i-th character from string (cause some characters requires two or more bytes).

Comment: Give this one a try:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12446877/php-is-it-possible-to-correctly-substr-a-utf-8-string

Comment: @CamilStaps, Not when you're using `rand`.

Comment: @OrelEraki the function is called RandomString. Guess what it does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few characters in your `$chars` array, that are multibyte characters (UTF-8 to be precise). Unfortunately, PHP doesn't handle multibyte characters that well on its own.

A solution here, is to replace all the calls with a variant that supports multibyte characters. The [mbstring](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php) extension provides such support.

You can replace a call as `$chars[rand(0,88)]` by a call to the [mb_substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php) function. So you get something like `mb_substr($chars, rand(0, 88), 1)`.

Comment: mb_substr($chars, rand(0,88),1,'utf8'); made the job.