# How to face with emojicons in strings?

Tags: php, emoji, multibyte

How to count emojicons as a single character?

I have the below record containing two emojicons and link propertries made by Telegram messageing app:

```
{ "text":"abc \ud83d\ude00\ud83e\udd23 www.google.com def", "entities": [{"offset":9,"length":14,"type":"url"}] }
```

I need to find the link in string, but using substr() and mb_substr() don't work properly on emojicons.

```
substr(9, 14)
```

returns

> "إ¸ثœâ‚¬ www.google"

which reads each emojicon as 4 characters

and

```
mb_substr(9, 14)
```

returns

> "w.google.com d"

which reads each emojicon as 1 character

I need a function to read each emojicon as 2 characters.

---

Edit: I need to clarify that there are other entities other than links. So finding just the links is not the true solution.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12446877/php-is-it-possible-to-correctly-substr-a-utf-8-string

Comment: @mega6382 this is not the solution. My case is a mixed string of utt-8 and emojicons. Each emojicon consists of 4 bytes

Answer (score 0):

for fetching URLs from an string you can do like this:

```
<?php
    $string = 'abc \ud83d\ude00\ud83e\udd23 www.google.com def';
    $sections = explode(' ', $string);
    $urls = array();
    foreach($sections as $section){
        preg_match('{\b(?:http://)?(www\.)?([^\s]+)(\.com|\.org|\.net)\b}mi', $section, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
        if(isset($matches[0][0]) and $matches[0][0]!='')
            $urls[] = $matches[0][0];
    }

    print_r($urls);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks. But I need to find the sub string addressed by entities array items. not just ordinal links

Comment: after your comment i researched about this and could not found solution, you can check and if there was a url in parameters do that with preg_match and fetch URLs